# Optimize way of Null checking for multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table with three columns and i want to take all rows where at least one column value is not null , right now i am using `coalesce()`below way for null checking and it is working fine

```
with Test_name AS(

    select null as id , null as f_name , null as l_name
    union ALL
    select 1,'fname1', null
    union ALL
    select null,null,null
) select tn.* from Test_name tn where coalesce(id,f_name,l_name) is not null
```

expected output and which gives me my query

```
1,'fname1', null
```

I am wonder is there any more better way to do this null checking

Comment: I don't know SQL Server very well, but I'd consider `where id is not null or f_name is not null or l_name is not null`. Perhaps easier to optimize?

Comment: Your code is fine.  What do you mean by a "better way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the row for not NULL values in three ways:

1. `COALESCE(col1, col2, col3) IS NOT NULL`
2. `col1 IS NOT NULL OR col2 IS NOT NULL OR col3 IS NOT NULL`
3. `ISNULL(col1, ISNULL(col2, ISNULL(col3, NULL))) IS NOT NULL`

You can use the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to compare multiple querys.

**result of comparison:**

- `COALESCE` vs. `IS NOT NULL`: 57% to 43%
- `COALESCE` vs. `ISNULL`: 56% to 44%
- `IS NOT NULL` vs. `ISNULL`: 49% to 51%

So using `IS NOT NULL` is the fastest way to check if a row has a column without a NULL value. In case of readability the `COALESCE` can be much shorter than a `IS NOT NULL` or `ISNULL` comparison. You can decide between readability and speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can add computed column like this

```
ALTER TABLE myTableName
ADD newColumnName AS (CASE
                    WHEN id IS NULL
                         AND fname IS NULL
                         AND lname IS NULL
                    THEN 0
                    ELSE 1
                END) PERSISTED
```

Then you can easily query your table

```
SELECT 
*
FROM myTable 
WHERE newColumnName = 1
```