# Return true (1), if a joined data entry exists, else false (0) in MS-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have an SQL statement that joins to two different tables in a 1 to 1 relationship each. For each of those joins, I want to return a `BIT` value (0 or 1), if the join was successful or not.

Let's say, we have a base table `Base` and the tables `A` and `B`, which are joined together via a `LEFT JOIN` on a common ID. I want to return the ID, as well as a field `IsA` and a field `IsB`.

What would be the best-practice solution to do this in Microsoft SQL Server most efficiently?

By the way, my current approach is this:

```
CAST(ISNULL(A.ID, 0) AS BIT) AS IsA,
CAST(ISNULL(B.ID, 0) AS BIT) AS IsB
```

Comment: Your solution is short (which is good), but it relies on the fact that converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1 (which might be non-intuitive). I think that the CASE-WHEN-solutions proposed in the answers are a bit more readable.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6777910/87698

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following, using `CASE WHEN` instead of `ISNULL`:

```
SELECT Base.*, A.id, B.id, 
  CAST(CASE WHEN A.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS IsA,
  CAST(CASE WHEN B.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS BIT) AS IsB
FROM Base LEFT JOIN A ON Base.id = A.base_id
  LEFT JOIN B ON Base.id = B.base_id
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=677a0bfaecb4ca777ab16d6bfe152dbc)

This solution, compared to your current approach, has the same efficiency. But also see [this answer (check multiple columns for `NULL` values)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56126328/3840840). There you can see the `ISNULL` solution is less efficient. In your case it makes no big difference.

**Also be careful:** The `ISNULL` can also return `0` in case the column values is `0`. So with your current approach you would get `False` in such a case.

Comment: Would that be more efficient than my current approach?

Comment: The last point is very important. Very convincing, that your solution is better.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would do it this way:

```
Cast(CASE WHEN A.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit) AS IsA
```

Comment: See @Sebastian's answer: Would that be more efficient than my current approach?

Comment: @AndréReichelt - assuming you have indexes on the join fields and your scenario is as described then this will be as efficient as you can get it. The approach I have shared should be equal to yours but I would say that this is _clearer_